# Pytest mock different behaviour to same function on loop

Tags: python, pytest

I'm having troubles on mocking the return value on looped lists. Imagine I have a function that paints the cars like this:

```
def do_operate(car_list: list):
    flawless_car_list = list()
    for car in car_list:
        if paint_the_car(car):
            flawless_car_list.append(car)
        else:
            print_log(f"{car} couldn't get painted")

    return flawless_car_list
```

On each iteration there's a some random error probability (like unable to connect to server, or couldn't get car details) that a car couldn't get painted for an unknown reason. We have tests to ensure that even a car can't get painted, we are continuing to paint the rest of the upcoming cars, and logging the erroneous cars.

If I test the happy path, everything is ok like this:

```
def test_happy_path(mocker):
    test_list = ["honda", "bmw", "ford"]
    mocker.patch("pytest1.paint_the_car", return_value=True)
    mocker.patch("pytest1.print_log")

    card_list = do_operate(car_list=test_list)

    assert len(card_list) == 3
    paint_the_car.assert_called()
    print_log.assert_not_called()
```

But at some point I need to be able to mock the `paint_car` like this `mocker.patch("pytest1.paint_the_car", return_value=False)` **for a specific car (second car)** and `mocker.patch("pytest1.paint_the_car", return_value=True)` for **first and third cars**. In the end, I would like to pass the assertions;

```
def test_error_occured_on_second_item(mocker):
    test_list = ["honda", "bmw", "ford"]

    # HOW TO CHANGE MOCKS?
    mocker.patch("pytest1.paint_the_car", return_value=True)
    mocker.patch("pytest1.print_log")

    card_list = do_operate(car_list=test_list)

    assert len(card_list) == 2
    paint_the_car.assert_called()
    print_log.assert_called_with("bmw couldn't get painted")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `side_effect` with a list of return values like so: `mocker.patch("pytest1.paint_the_car", side_effect = [True, False, True])` then it would return `True` for the first and 3rd calls, and `False` for the second call.

See official docs for [side effect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#:%7E:text=mock.side_effect%20%3D%20%5B5%2C%204%2C%203%2C%202%2C%201%5D%0A%3E%3E%3E).